# How to expose port from host to container in Docker?

Tags: docker

You can use [EXPOSE](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#expose) in Docker for:

> The EXPOSE instructions informs Docker that the container will listen
>   on the specified network ports at runtime.

Can I do the opposite? Can I expose port from my Ubuntu to the docker container?

**Background:** I'm trying to setup a simple php7-fpm as a docker image and I would like to expose port 3306 (MySQL service) to the docker container.

My `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM debian:jessie

# persistent / runtime deps
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ca-certificates curl libpcre3 librecode0 libsqlite3-0 libxml2 --no-install-recommends && rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# phpize deps
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y autoconf file g++ gcc libc-dev make pkg-config re2c --no-install-recommends && rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV PHP_INI_DIR /usr/local/etc/php
RUN mkdir -p $PHP_INI_DIR/conf.d

##<autogenerated>##
ENV PHP_EXTRA_CONFIGURE_ARGS --enable-fpm --with-fpm-user=www-data --with-fpm-group=www-data
##</autogenerated>##

ENV PHP_VERSION 7.0.0RC2

# --enable-mysqlnd is included below because it's harder to compile after the fact the extensions are (since it's a plugin for several extensions, not an extension in itself)
RUN buildDeps=" \
        $PHP_EXTRA_BUILD_DEPS \
        libcurl4-openssl-dev \
        libpcre3-dev \
        libreadline6-dev \
        librecode-dev \
        libsqlite3-dev \
        libssl-dev \
        libxml2-dev \
        xz-utils \
    " \
    && set -x \
    && apt-get update && apt-get install -y $buildDeps --no-install-recommends && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && curl -SL "https://downloads.php.net/~ab/php-$PHP_VERSION.tar.xz" -o php.tar.xz \
    && mkdir -p /usr/src/php \
    && tar -xof php.tar.xz -C /usr/src/php --strip-components=1 \
    && rm php.tar.xz* \
    && cd /usr/src/php \
    && ./configure \
        --with-config-file-path="$PHP_INI_DIR" \
        --with-config-file-scan-dir="$PHP_INI_DIR/conf.d" \
        $PHP_EXTRA_CONFIGURE_ARGS \
        --disable-cgi \
        --enable-mysqlnd \
        --with-pdo-mysql \
        --enable-mbstring \
        --with-curl \       
        --with-openssl \
        --with-pcre \
        --with-readline \
        --with-recode \
        --with-zlib \
    && make -j"$(nproc)" \
    && make install \
    && { find /usr/local/bin /usr/local/sbin -type f -executable -exec strip --strip-all '{}' + || true; } \
    && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove -o APT::AutoRemove::RecommendsImportant=false -o APT::AutoRemove::SuggestsImportant=false $buildDeps \
    && make clean

COPY docker-php-ext-* /usr/local/bin/

##<autogenerated>##
WORKDIR /var/www/html
COPY php-fpm.conf /usr/local/etc/

EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["php-fpm"]
##</autogenerated>##
```

This is the command I use to run my container:

```
docker run --name=php7-fpm -v /var/www/html/:/var/www/html/ -p 9002:9000 marty/php7
```

My PHP app database configuration:

```
database:
    main:
        host: 127.0.0.1
        dbname: edu
        user: root
        password: myPassword
        port: 3306
```

Comment: So you have a MySQL service running on your Ubuntu and you want to use it in your Docker container? If so, you got nothing to do. There is no Docker magic for this. It will work if you use the correct IP.

Comment: If you have problems with this (I think you have as you ask a question here), please show us your Dockerfile, the run command and what ifconfig says.

Comment: I have added the Dockerfile. I'm getting `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused` from my PHP application now.

Comment: This indicates that the port is not opened. (I tried to change MySQL connection credentials to make sure that the error is caused by the port issue)

Comment: Where do you configure the SQL connection?

Comment: In my PHP application in a configuration file and it works fine with `php5-fpm` on my host.

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: Your config file says that your database is running on `127.0.0.1`. But if you are inside your Docker container, `127.0.0.1` is the container itself. But your database is not running in the container, it runs on your host. You must provide the IP address of your host here.

Comment: Ah, well, this is what my question is about. I would like to map 127.0.0.1:3306 (my host) to 127.0.0.1:3306 (docker container).

Comment: Ah, OK, we are getting to it :) That's not possible as far as I know. You must provide the IP of the host manually for the container. Sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run container with `--net=host` then it will have access to the host's ports directly. See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings